# Knockout if binding inside a template does not show now matter what value the observable holds?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js

I have a simple template with an if binding inside it:

```
<script type="text/html" id="addPersonTemplate">
   <tr>
    ...
    <td class="large-7" data-bind="text: addPersonUsername"><span class="noSpecificChecks" data-bind="if: addPersonUsername() == false">No username added</span></td>
    ...
   </tr>
</script>
```

Basically, a person has an option to enter a username. When they click 'add' somewhere else in the document, the template is outputted, however, no matter what I try:

I cannot get `if: addPersonUsername() == false` to evaluate correctly.

If the expression evaluates to true (there is no username) I want to output "No username added". Yet, if I enter no username, the addPersonUsername() variable is undefined (checked via `console.log`) and yet this text is not outputted.

Is there any particular reason for this? Is the if binding only evaluated at HTML page load, not at template addition? I can't see any indication it is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knockout observables are functions so you need to get their value with calling them without any argument (e.g.: `addPersonUsername()`) when they are used in any expression like inside an `if` binding:

```
<span class="noSpecificChecks" data-bind="if: addPersonUsername() == false">
```

Beside that your HTML is structured incorrectly. When you apply the `text` binding on the `td` it replaces the whole content of the `td` so also your span with the `if`.

So you need to apply the text something else inside the `td` like on a `span` (or use the virtual element syntax if you don't need the `span`):

```
<td class="large-7" > 
      <!-- ko if: addPersonUsername --> 
          <span data-bind="text: addPersonUsername"></span>
      <!-- /ko -->
      <span class="noSpecificChecks" data-bind="if: addPersonUsername() == false">No username added
      </span>
</td>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p3k3b2rf/).

Comment: Hmm. Still not working. I have tried to evaluate it as an expression before with no luck. `console.log()` tells me `addPersonUsername()` evaluates to undefined, so it should be appearing (undefined == false is true in JS, correct?)

Comment: You also have a problem with your text binding. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Ahh, gotchya'. So it's the parent text binding causing the issue. Cheers.